I made a one-card game, but it keeps falling into infinite loop
I've tried implementing a one-card game with c, but my code is that when I run about 5 times, I fall into infinite loop at least 2 times. I've talked to chat-gpt a lot to solve this problem, but I haven't found an answer... Please fix it!
Below is the code I tried, please tell me the problem, the code works as intended unless it falls into an infinite loop
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_CARDS 52
#define NUM_SUITS 4
#define NUM_RANKS 13
#define INITIAL_HAND_SIZE 5
#define MAX_HAND_SIZE 16

typedef struct {
    char *suit;
    char *rank;
    int value;
} Card;

typedef struct {
    Card hand[MAX_HAND_SIZE];
    int handSize;
} Player;

const char *suits[] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
const char *ranks[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};

Card deck[NUM_CARDS];
Player player, computer;
Card openCard;
int deckIndex = 0;
int drawCount = 0;

// Function prototypes
void initialize_deck();
void shuffle_deck();
void deal_cards();
void print_hand(Player *p);
void take_turn(Player *current, Player *opponent, int *turn);
void play_card(Player *p, int cardIndex);
void draw_card(Player *p, int count);
int check_victory(Player *p);
int check_defeat(Player *p);
void apply_attack_card(Player *attacker, Player *defender, int attackValue);
void start_game();
int canPlayCard(Card c);
int isAttackCard(Card c);

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    start_game();
    return 0;
}

void initialize_deck() {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SUITS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_RANKS; j++) {
            deck[k].suit = (char *)suits[i];
            deck[k].rank = (char *)ranks[j];
            deck[k].value = j + 2;
            k++;
        }
    }
    shuffle_deck();
}

void shuffle_deck() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARDS; i++) {
        int r = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (NUM_CARDS - i) + 1);
        Card temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[r];
        deck[r] = temp;
    }
}

void deal_cards() {
    player.handSize = INITIAL_HAND_SIZE;
    computer.handSize = INITIAL_HAND_SIZE;
    for (int i = 0; i < INITIAL_HAND_SIZE; i++) {
        player.hand[i] = deck[deckIndex++];
        computer.hand[i] = deck[deckIndex++];
    }
    openCard = deck[deckIndex++];
}

void print_hand(Player *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p->handSize; i++) {
        printf("%s of %s\n", p->hand[i].rank, p->hand[i].suit);
    }
}

void take_turn(Player *current, Player *opponent, int *turn) {
    printf("%s's turn!\n", current == &player ? "Player" : "Computer");
    printf("Open card: %s of %s\n", openCard.rank, openCard.suit);
    print_hand(current);
    int played = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < current->handSize; i++) {
        if (canPlayCard(current->hand[i])) {
            play_card(current, i);
            played = 1;
            if (isAttackCard(openCard)) {
                apply_attack_card(current, opponent, openCard.value == 2 ? 2 : 4);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!played) {
        printf("No playable card. Drawing a card...\n");
        draw_card(current, 1);
    }
    if (check_defeat(current)) {
        printf("%s loses!\n", current == &player ? "Player" : "Computer");
        exit(0);
    } else if (check_victory(current)) {
        printf("%s wins!\n", current == &player ? "Player" : "Computer");
        exit(0);
    }
    *turn = 1 - *turn;
}

void play_card(Player *p, int cardIndex) {
    openCard = p->hand[cardIndex];
    p->handSize--;
    for (int i = cardIndex; i < p->handSize; i++) {
        p->hand[i] = p->hand[i + 1];
    }
    printf("%s played: %s of %s\n", p == &player ? "Player" : "Computer", openCard.rank, openCard.suit);
}

void draw_card(Player *p, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (deckIndex < NUM_CARDS) {
            p->hand[p->handSize++] = deck[deckIndex++];
        }
    }
}

int check_victory(Player *p) {
    return p->handSize == 0;
}

int check_defeat(Player *p) {
    return p->handSize >= MAX_HAND_SIZE;
}

int canPlayCard(Card c) {
    return c.value == openCard.value || c.suit == openCard.suit;
}

int isAttackCard(Card c) {
    return c.value == 2 || c.value == 14; 
}

void apply_attack_card(Player *attacker, Player *defender, int attackValue) {
    int hasDefense = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < defender->handSize; i++) {
        if (defender->hand[i].value == 2 || defender->hand[i].value == 14) {
            hasDefense = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasDefense) {
        printf("%s draws %d cards.\n", defender == &player ? "Player" : "Computer", attackValue);
        draw_card(defender, attackValue);
    } else {
        printf("%s has an attack card to defend.\n", defender == &player ? "Player" : "Computer");
    }
}

void start_game() {
    initialize_deck();
    deal_cards();
    int turn = 0;
    while (1) {
        if (turn == 0) {
            take_turn(&player, &computer, &turn);
            if (check_victory(&player) || check_defeat(&computer)) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            take_turn(&computer, &player, &turn);
            if (check_victory(&computer) || check_defeat(&player)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried implementing a one-card game with c, but my code is that when I run about 5 times, I fall into infinite loop at least 2 times. I've talked to chat-gpt a lot to solve this problem, but I haven't found an answer... Please fix it!
Below is the code I tried, please tell me the problem, the code works as intended unless it falls into an infinite loop

A similar question has been asked not too long ago. How is this one different?

Please edit your question and remove the code dump. We only need to see a Minimal, Reproduceable example.  Then add details about what you have found in your debugging.

At least give us the input you enter into the game to make it get into the erroneous state.

Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem. If you are unable to provide shorter code, then please at least seed the random number generator with a fixed value instead of srand(time(NULL));, so that your program behaves the same way every time you run it, and the error is reproducible. For example, are you able to reproduce the error with srand(1);? What about srand(2); or srand(3);?

Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems? You may also want to read this: How to debug small programs?

Trying out your code, I too ran into the occasional instance where the program gets stuck in an infinite loop.  Doing a cursive view of the printed data at the terminal led me to add in a "printf" statement in the "draw_card" function.
void draw_card(Player *p, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (deckIndex < NUM_CARDS)
        {
            p->hand[p->handSize++] = deck[deckIndex++];
        }
        printf("Hand size: %d  Deck index: %d\n", p->handSize, deckIndex);
    }
}

What this helped illustrate in the terminal output is that there is no testing or accommodation for the scenario where all of the cards in the deck have been drawn, but neither player has a card that they can play.  Following is a snippet of the repeating scenario showing neither the computer or player having a card that can be played and no more cards to draw.
Computer's turn!
Open card: K of Spades
10 of Diamonds
3 of Diamonds
8 of Hearts
5 of Diamonds
No playable card. Drawing a card...
Hand size: 4  Deck index: 52
Player's turn!
Open card: K of Spades
J of Diamonds
2 of Diamonds
9 of Diamonds
Q of Diamonds
Q of Hearts
Q of Clubs
7 of Diamonds
10 of Clubs
10 of Hearts
No playable card. Drawing a card...
Hand size: 9  Deck index: 52

I will leave it to you to add in the logic to call that condition a draw or whether the winner is the player with the least number of cards once that scenario is met.
